# Redefine 'psychology' tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

The tag [psychology](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/psychology) current has the following tag wiki excerpt:

> Questions relating to psychological influence on an opponent during a game.

There are currently 55 questions with this tag, and not all of them are about this type of influence during the game. For example,

- [Facing irregular or uncommon openings](https://chess.stackexchange.com/q/14243/10867) is not about the opponent but about openings.
- [How do I become less materialistic?](https://chess.stackexchange.com/q/14231/10867) is about a more general approach during the game.
- [Why do people say blitz chess can be bad for your chess?](https://chess.stackexchange.com/q/14210/10867) is essentially more cognitively oriented.
- [Chess helps academic performance?](https://chess.stackexchange.com/q/12204/10867).

Chess psychology is much broader than what the current tag wiki excerpt suggest. I would propose the following definition, unless there are good reasons to create additional tags for specific aspects of chess psychology:

> Questions related to cognitive, motivational and other psychological aspects of chess, both during and before/after games.

Comment: Go ahead and propose it.

Comment: @DagOskarMadsen OK, I have submitted the proposal :-)